# Store the drop down selected value in a SESSION variable

Tags: php, html, session

Im getting a set of values from the database to show in a drop down list. Once the user selected an item from the drop down list the selected item should be assigned to a SESSION variable. I tried this but yet it is not working. Please smeone help me to sort it out.

```
<select id="FormNameSelecting" style="position:absolute; width:300px; top:50px; left:200px; "><option></option>
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
    echo "<option  value='$row[Form_ID]'>$row[Form_Name]</option>";
    echo 
    }
?>
</select>
```

So I need to store these values receive from $row[Form_ID] and $row[Form_Name] in 2 session variables named $_SESSION['Form_ID'] and $_SESSION['Form_Name']; Could someone explain me how I can assign the selected item's values to these two session variables.

Comment: do you want to store id into session on change selected item or after submitting the form or select

Comment: :) I need to do it for onchange event.

Comment: Then firstly you have to add some kind of ajax or javascript to get value on cnage

Comment: Check Out the answer which gives you method to get value from ajax. and make a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

The selected `option` element must have `selected` attribute.
You should try something like this:

```
<select id="FormNameSelecting" style="position:absolute; width:300px; top:50px; left:200px; ">
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {      
      echo "<option  value='{$row['Form_ID']}'";

      if($row['Form_ID'] == $_SESSION['Form_ID'])
        echo " selected";

      echo ">{$row['Form_Name']}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can store it in `$_SESSION` after the form submit

```php
<?php
  session_start(); // dont forget it!  

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $_SESSION['Form_ID'] = $_POST['Form_ID']; 
    $_SESSION['Form_Name'] = $_POST['Form_Name']; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Here is the first time I'm initiating a session variable. I have not mentioned a $_SESSION['Form_ID'] variable. So don't I need to assign the $row['Form_ID'] instead checking they are equal to each other. And could you please explain me why the option must have a selected attribute. :)

Comment: You have to add selected attribute beaceuse of [html specify](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form name="my_name" method="POST" action="">
<select name="FormNameSelecting" id="FormNameSelecting" style="position:absolute; width:300px; top:50px; left:200px; "> //don't forget put name at select
<option></option>
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //prefer using assoc that array     
    echo "<option  value='" . $row['Form_ID'] . ":::" . $row['Form_Name'] . "'>" . $row['Form_Name'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="go"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){

    $store_sesi = explode(":::",$_POST['FormNameSelecting']);
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $store[0];
    $_SESSION['Name'] = $store[1];
}
?>
```

hope this code help you

Comment: hii thank you so much for replying. :) Why do we use the explode method?
    $store_sesi = explode(":::",$_POST['FormNameSelecting']);

Comment: if you see the option i modify at myanswer, i have join 2 value as one value at one option.. and the value is separated by `:::` and you can use other separated you want... then i sent the value via POST, i need to split the value again.. and in PHP i use `explode()`, and the result of explode will become array...

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**
In your page add this and create one more page "showValues.php"(This is the page where you want to create and use your session variable).Code of showValues.php is also given below for example.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
function showValue(vals)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var val= xmlhttp.responseText;

            document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML+=val;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showValues.php?vals="+vals,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="FormNameSelecting" style="position:absolute; width:300px; top:50px; left:200px; "><option></option>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
echo "<option  value='$row[Form_ID]'>$row[Form_Name]</option>";
echo 
}
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**showValues.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$vals=$_REQUEST['vals'];
$_SESSION['SelectValue']=$vals;
echo $_SESSION['SelectValue'];
?>
```